# Launching Eclipse feature based project

Tags: eclipse-rcp, xtend

I am running Eclipse Photon under Java 10 on Windows 10. I created a RCP plugin based project using Xtend instead of Java and using the Eclipse E4 application template and I could launch it without problem. However when I converted it to a feature based project it fails to resolve the bundle `com.google.guava`.

The console output is here:

```
WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.httpclient
!SESSION 2018-07-26 09:15:52.713 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=10.0.2
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.example.e4.rcp.wizard.product -clearPersistedState
Command-line arguments:  -product com.example.e4.rcp.wizard.product -data D:\WiseOldBird\Workspaces\VogellaRcpXtend/../runtime-com.example.e4.rcp.wizard.product -dev file:D:/WiseOldBird/Workspaces/VogellaRcpXtend/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/com.example.e4.rcp.wizard.product/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -consoleLog -clearPersistedState

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.app 0 0 2018-07-26 09:15:53.916
!MESSAGE Product com.example.e4.rcp.wizard.product could not be found.

!ENTRY com.example.e4.rcp.wizard 2 0 2018-07-26 09:15:54.001
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: com.example.e4.rcp.wizard [150]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.google.guava


!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-07-26 09:15:54.008
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: No application id has been found.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:656)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1471)
An error has occurred. See the log file
D:\WiseOldBird\Workspaces\VogellaRcpXtend\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\com.example.e4.rcp.wizard.product\1532614553207.log.
```

My manifest.mf file is:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Wizard
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.example.e4.rcp.wizard;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Vendor: EXAMPLE
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime;bundle-version="0.0.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench;bundle-version="0.0.0",
 org.eclipse.jface;bundle-version="0.0.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench;bundle-version="0.0.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.core.di;bundle-version="0.0.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.di;bundle-version="0.0.0",
 com.google.guava,
 org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib,
 org.eclipse.xtend.lib,
 org.eclipse.xtend.lib.macro
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-9
Import-Package: javax.annotation;version="0.0.0"
Automatic-Module-Name: com.example.e4.rcp.wizard
```

My feature.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feature
      id="com.example.e4.rcp.wizard.feature"
      label="Feature"
      version="1.0.0.qualifier">

   <description url="http://www.example.com/description">
      [Enter Feature Description here.]
   </description>

   <copyright url="http://www.example.com/copyright">
      [Enter Copyright Description here.]
   </copyright>

   <license url="http://www.example.com/license">
      [Enter License Description here.]
   </license>

   <requires>
      <import plugin="javax.inject"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.runtime"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.swt"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.jface"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.e4.ui.services"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.e4.core.di"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.e4.ui.di"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.xtend.lib"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.xtend.lib.macro"/>
      <import plugin="javax.annotation"/>
      <import plugin="com.google.guava"/>
   </requires>

   <plugin
         id="com.example.e4.rcp.wizard"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

</feature>
```

What do I need to do to be able to launch this as a feature based project?

Comment: How did you build the RCP? If this was Export > Eclipse Product check the export directory for a logs.zip file. Export doesn't work properly with Java 10.

Comment: No, I am simply trying to launch within Eclipse at this point but I will need to export this as well. So it seems you are saying that Java 10 is not usable if you want a RCP application or Eclipse plugin.

Comment: There are several ways to build, I am told Maven + Tycho works.

Answer (score 1):

`import` in the feature.xml means that some other feature provides those plugins. If you are only specifying your feature they won't be found.

For e4 the `org.eclipse.e4.rcp`, `org.eclipse.emf.common` and `org.eclipse.emf.ecore` features should also be included in the product file or Run Configuration.

Plugins not in the other features should be listed in the 'Included Plug-ins' list in your feature.xml